# Search visual selction in emacs evil

Tags: vim, emacs, elisp, evil-mode

I want to emulate a behavior I've had in vim, but in emacs evil-mode. I want `*` to search for the current visually selected text. The code below sort of works, but pressing `n` or `N` does not retain the search string

```
(define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd "*")
  (lambda () (interactive)
    (let ((search-string (buffer-substring
                          (evil-range-beginning (evil-visual-range))
                          (evil-range-end (evil-visual-range)))))
      (evil-normal-state)
      (evil-search search-string t))))
```

I'm new to emacs/elisp. Any ideas on what the "right way" to do this is? In the [evil-search.el source](https://github.com/emacsmirror/evil/blob/master/evil-search.el) I see a function `evil-ex-search-update-pattern` that may be useful, but I'm not sure how to put it together.

Thanks!

Comment: You have also this: https://github.com/bling/evil-visualstar (to install, or peek at the implementation)

Comment: Ah! That's much easier than cobbling my own stuff together. Thanks! You can answer with that, and I'll accept it.

Comment: You're welcome! and done. BTW, for emacs questions, there's also http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest (dedicated)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bailey Ling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PeVQwYUxYEg) (a former Vim user) has made a plugin that accomplishes the same thing you're after: https://github.com/bling/evil-visualstar.

You can either install it, or peek through the source code (which may help solve your issue).